# Stuffing text into a screen tab only after the shell has loaded

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

I'm setting up my `screenrc` to open several tabs and already insert commands such that I only need to press enter to start some process.

Here's an example `screenrc`:

```
screen -t test
stuff hello
```

However, if I start screen, the text "hello" will appear twice, because `stuff` is executed *before* the shell has loaded. This is what it looks like with my shell and the above `screenrc`:

[image: screen session]

How can I avoid the first "hello" shown in the terminal before the shell has loaded?

Comment: Is this an end in itself? If not, what larger goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I simply don't like the clutter.

Comment: But are you trying to run a command (in which case you don't need `stuff`), to just print a thing (in which case `.bashrc` seems sufficient), or something else?

Comment: The goal is to have a screen session that fills a number of tabs with predefined commands so I only need to press enter to start. I don't want anything to start automatically, but I also don't want to type the commands manually. If there's an alternative to stuff, I'd be happy to use it

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can test this, but something like (as a line in the screen rc file) `screen sh -c 'echo some-command; read && some-command; sh'` should allow a pseudo pre-filling, cancellable by ctrl-c

Comment: okay, that sounds reasonable, although I was hoping for a more built-in solution